# How does adding a random number to the end of an AJAX server request prevent caching?

Tags: ajax, caching, get

How exactly does adding a random number to the end of an AJAX server call prevent the database server or browser (not entirely sure which one is intended) from caching? why does this work?

Comment: It's the connection between the browser and the web server that can be affected by caches (in the browser or somewhere closer to the server). Note that this does not affect the database server - caching for that is a very different matter, and is not relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is intended to prevent client-side (or reverse proxy) caching.

Since the cache will be keyed on the exact request, by adding a random element to the request, the exact request URL should never be seen twice; so it won't be used more than once, and an intelligent cache won't bother keeping around something that's never been seen more than once, at least, not for long.

Answer (score 2):

It's to prevent your browser (and to a reasonable amount, a web proxy) from caching requests. Typically, a query parameter - like ?rand2024= tells the browser/proxy to send the onward request with a parameter telling your application to behave differently. That's why such requests are useful to bust caches.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser caches the web page keyed by the exact text of the URL, so adding a random-number parameter ensures that the URL is different every time - thus no *real* caching. Your browser doesn't know that the server is (hopefully) ignoring this parameter.