# Avoid data caching when using d3.text

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3.text() to load a text file. I want to avoid using the cache of the browser. Anybody knows how this can be done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't see how the MIME type would do anything for this issue.

You can avoid caching by appending a random number to the url (this is a general practice that has nothing to do with d3). So, if your url is

`var url = 'http://www.example.com/somthing';`

Then make your request

```
 d3.text(
   url + '?' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
 );
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106621/how-does-adding-a-random-number-to-the-end-of-an-ajax-server-request-prevent-cac)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer! I thought I could change the headers of the HTTP get request with that second (MIME) argument. I edited my question to avoid a non-desirable matching for MIME related queries.