# d3.js data not refreshing upon change in the file

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have 5 csv files 1.csv,2.csv.. 5.csv. What I am doing is I have a dropdown list. When I select a particular option from the dropdown list a particular file will be loaded and visualized. The data in the files are changing regularly. But the problem is when I select a particular file the data is somehow stored may be in cache. So no change in the file later is taken. Even if I remove the file from the directory the visualization is shown with data loaded first time. I even tried with refreshing the page.
My code is following:

```
selector.on("change", function(d){
    var selectedKey = keys[this.selectedIndex];
    d3.csv(selectedKey +".csv", function(data){
console.log(selectedKey +".txt");
    //var format = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S");
    var format = d3.time.format("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S");
    data.forEach(function (e){
            e.dist = +e.dist;
            e.speed = +e.speed;
            e.lat=+e.lat;
            e.lon=+e.lon;               
            e.dd=format.parse(e.time);
            //console.log(e.dd);
    });
    dataset=data;
    var ndx = crossfilter(data);
    dimx = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.bearing});
    g = dimx.group(function(v){return v;});
    var output = g.top(Infinity);

}

    });
```

Can anyone help me to find the problem? After selecting 2.csv the chart is first time shown fine. Then when I change data in 2.csv the visualization is shown with previous data. Even I delete 2.csv file from the directory the visualizations are shown with previous data. This happens even after refreshing the page and reselecting the key also

Comment: Please provide a complete example. I'm pretty sure this `d3.csv(selectedKey +".csv", function(data){}` is not your actual code...

Comment: Some more code added. That should make sense I think. Other codes are just drawing plot taking the dataset variable

Comment: Now that I think about it, I wonder if this is just a straight up browser cache issue.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053096/avoid-data-caching-when-using-d3-text).

Comment: Yap got it. That helped

Answer (score 2):

```
d3.csv(selectedKey +".csv"+'?' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function(data){}
```

Will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is the question I've been searching an answer for. I have csv data that d3 displays on a table. The csv file is continuously being updated but the old data still displays until I refresh the page. I hope this `d3.csv(selectedKey +".csv"+'?' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function(data){}` will work. Though, mine will be this something like this `d3.csv( "csvfile.csv"+'?' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000).then( function(data){})`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).